# create session in symfony and get it in another system

Tags: php, symfony

How can i create a session in Symphony , and get in another system?

I try this from to get:

```
 $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']; // but not work
```

if i have session i am redirected to another system and there i want get this session how i can to do this?

```
if(isset($_SESSION['_sf2_attributes']['_school_list']) && $data == 'OK') {
        return $this->redirect('', 302);
    }
```

in another system i try get session from cookie:

```
    if($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']){
            session_id($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']);
        }

        session_start();

dump($_SESSION);die; // empty
```

Comment: What "another system" means to you?

Comment: You cannot access cookies from other domain., (or system ... whatever)

Comment: exist old system in one domain, i want re-build to new technologies. I start from login controller. ( new system will be in symfony )

Answer (score 0):

You should store the session in an external storage (like redis), configure your systems to read sessions from Redis and make sure that your PHPSESSID reaches both machines untouched (just in case you are putting them behind a load balancer or proxy or whatever)